# Where is the list of fields available through the openFDA API?

Tags: openfda

I was wondering how to create a query based off the examples, and the main question I have is where do the `patient.drug.openfda.pharm_class_epc` and 
`patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt` come from?

I understand that there are many fields to choose from, but is there some sort of list from which we can find different possible fields?

I am fine with the syntax and understand the parameters, as well as how the results are displayed, but I cannot toy with the examples much because I do not understand what the syntax of different fields are for searching and counting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few sources for the information you're looking for (essentially a data dictionary if I am understanding your question correctly):

- [List of OpenFDA Fields](https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#openfda-fields) (data OpenFDA has added/annotated for developer and user convenience on top of the base FAERS data fields)
- [FAERS/AERS Mapping Notes](https://github.com/FDA/openfda/blob/master/schemas/faers_mapping.md) which are part of the Github project and document some caveats about fields like `primarysource.reportercountry`
- Lastly, the one of the great parts of the OpenFDA team using ElasticSearch as a backend is that you can query by literally any field you see returned to you. So you could look at the sample queries, look at the fields, and query that way.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here on github. It is the schema in JSON and .md formats.

https://github.com/FDA/openfda/tree/master/schemas

Answer (score 0):

I did my own analysis to find all fields that show up.

```
fields: {
'id': {
    type: 'string'
},
'version': {
    type: 'string'
},
'set_id': {
    type: 'string'
},
'openfda': {
    type: 'object'
}, // the openFDA meta data
'effective_time': {
    type: 'string'
},
'abuse': {
    type: 'array'
},
'active_ingredient': {
    type: 'array'
},
'active_ingredient_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'adverse_reactions': {
    type: 'array'
},
'adverse_reactions_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'animal_pharmacology_and_or_toxicology': {
    type: 'array'
},
'ask_doctor': {
    type: 'array'
},
'ask_doctor_or_pharmacist': {
    type: 'array'
},
'boxed_warning': {
    type: 'array'
},
'carcinogenesis_and_mutagenesis_and_impairment_of_fertility': {
    type: 'array'
},
'clinical_pharmacology': {
    type: 'array'
},
'clinical_pharmacology_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'clinical_studies': {
    type: 'array'
},
'clinical_studies_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'contraindications': {
    type: 'array'
},
'contraindications_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'controlled_substance': {
    type: 'array'
},
'dependence': {
    type: 'array'
},
'description': {
    type: 'array'
},
'description_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'do_not_use': {
    type: 'array'
},
'dosage_and_administration': {
    type: 'array'
},
'dosage_and_administration_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'dosage_forms_and_strengths': {
    type: 'array'
},
'dosage_forms_and_strengths_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'drug_abuse_and_dependence': {
    type: 'array'
},
'drug_and_or_laboratory_test_interactions': {
    type: 'array'
},
'drug_interactions': {
    type: 'array'
},
'drug_interactions_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'general_precautions': {
    type: 'array'
},
'geriatric_use': {
    type: 'array'
},
'geriatric_use_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'how_supplied': {
    type: 'array'
},
'how_supplied_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'inactive_ingredient': {
    type: 'array'
},
'indications_and_usage': {
    type: 'array'
},
'indications_and_usage_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'information_for_patients': {
    type: 'array'
},
'instructions_for_use': {
    type: 'array'
},
'keep_out_of_reach_of_children': {
    type: 'array'
},
'labor_and_delivery': {
    type: 'array'
},
'laboratory_tests': {
    type: 'array'
},
'mechanism_of_action': {
    type: 'array'
},
'microbiology': {
    type: 'array'
},
'microbiology_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'nonclinical_toxicology': {
    type: 'array'
},
'nonteratogenic_effects': {
    type: 'array'
},
'nursing_mothers': {
    type: 'array'
},
'other_safety_information': {
    type: 'array'
},
'overdosage': {
    type: 'array'
},
'package_label_principal_display_panel': {
    type: 'array'
},
'patient_medication_information': {
    type: 'array'
},
'patient_medication_information_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pediatric_use': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pharmacodynamics': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pharmacokinetics': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pharmacokinetics_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'precautions': {
    type: 'array'
},
'precautions_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pregnancy': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pregnancy_or_breast_feeding': {
    type: 'array'
},
'purpose': {
    type: 'array'
},
'purpose_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'questions': {
    type: 'array'
},
'recent_major_changes': {
    type: 'array'
},
'references': {
    type: 'array'
},
'references_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'spl_medguide': {
    type: 'array'
},
'spl_medguide_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'spl_patient_package_insert': {
    type: 'array'
},
'spl_patient_package_insert_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'spl_product_data_elements': {
    type: 'array'
},
'spl_unclassified_section': {
    type: 'array'
},
'spl_unclassified_section_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'stop_use': {
    type: 'array'
},
'storage_and_handling': {
    type: 'array'
},
'teratogenic_effects': {
    type: 'array'
},
'use_in_specific_populations': {
    type: 'array'
},
'use_in_specific_populations_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'user_safety_warnings': {
    type: 'array'
},
'warnings': {
    type: 'array'
},
'warnings_and_cautions': {
    type: 'array'
},
'warnings_and_cautions_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'warnings_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'when_using': {
    type: 'array'
},
'recent_major_changes_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pediatric_use_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'instructions_for_use_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pharmacodynamics_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'information_for_patients_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'package_label_principal_display_panel_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'risks': {
    type: 'array'
},
'safe_handling_warning': {
    type: 'array'
},
'general_precautions_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pharmacogenomics': {
    type: 'array'
},
'nonclinical_toxicology_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'carcinogenesis_and_mutagenesis_and_impairment_of_fertility_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'storage_and_handling_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'inactive_ingredient_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'questions_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'abuse_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'drug_abuse_and_dependence_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'overdosage_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'components': {
    type: 'array'
},
'health_care_provider_letter': {
    type: 'array'
},
'intended_use_of_the_device': {
    type: 'array'
},
'mechanism_of_action_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'troubleshooting': {
    type: 'array'
},
'boxed_warning_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'health_care_provider_letter_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'statement_of_identity': {
    type: 'array'
},
'nonteratogenic_effects_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'pregnancy_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'stop_use_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'laboratory_tests_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'disposal_and_waste_handling': {
    type: 'array'
},
'information_for_owners_or_caregivers': {
    type: 'array'
},
'drug_and_or_laboratory_test_interactions_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'health_claim': {
    type: 'array'
},
'accessories': {
    type: 'array'
},
'teratogenic_effects_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'animal_pharmacology_and_or_toxicology_table': {
    type: 'array'
},
'route': {
    type: 'array'
},
'veterinary_indications': {
    type: 'array'
}
```

}