# Is it possible to get a complete list of medical devices through OpenFDA?

Tags: openfda, uses-of-open-data, medical

I was trying to get a complete list of medical devices through [openFDA](https://open.fda.gov/device/event/), but then I came to realize that through that data set the list can never be complete, since I can only get devices involved in a event report.

If I run https://api.fda.gov/device/recall.json?count=openfda.device_name.exact I will never get, for example, a tongue depressor, if a tongue depressor has never been involved in a adverse event.

I was going to try by getting device's categories, such as https://api.fda.gov/device/classification.json?&count=medical_specialty_description and then running queries to get devices by `medical_specialty_description` or similar field, but I'm still reading the site's documentation, trying to learn about heir API and [lists of terms available for searches](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3251/9568)

How, if it is possible, can a get a list of medical devices permitted by the FDA by  using openFDA?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this information is available through openFDA. You might want to file a feature request on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [AccessGUDID](http://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/), from the National Library of Medicine.